# How and when to persist user interactions (upvotes / likes) using React & Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to understand how to best implement this:

I have a CRUD app built in React / Redux / Postgres and I want the ability to persist something like user upvotes on an article. With Redux, I can simply fire an action that toggles it on/off, but if I want to keep track of how many upvotes it has, I have to persist each upvote to my postgres database.

Here's what I'm thinking so far, but not sure if this is the correct way to handle something like this:

On the click of the upvote, an action should fire increasing the vote value in redux. The POST request to my server would then be made via an action creator called within componentWillReceiveProps() as the store updates and passes in updated props.

Is this correct?

Thanks, any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a better idea to keep your store in sync with your db, and use the local state of the component to store the temporary upvote until the backend replies back. Thus you can do somehow like this:

1. Trigger an action and set local state of the component to +1 vote
2. The action sends a POST request, and on the successful reply sends an update to the redux store
3. The component receives props with the new value (that reflects the actual update of the db) and flushes its state in the componentWillReceiveProps hook. In case there can be other updates coming in to the component, you can avoid flushing state by checking if props did actually change.

This is a somehow a naive example, since in the real world application you would probably want to add error handling and communicate failed requests to the user